# Single IIS, 2 applications, 2 IP addresses, 2 Domains, 2 SSLs

Tags: iis, iis-7, ssl-certificate, host-headers

I know there are many questions out there, but none seemed to address specifically what I am after.

I have one instance of IIS, with two separate applications on it.  Each application works on its own URL, with it's own IP address and domain, and each domain has its own certificate.

How can I set up IIS to server up the correct combination based on the correct host?

Answer (score 1):

Through bindings.  Assuming you've already imported your SSL certs:

1. Create 2 web sites in IIS.
2. Edit the https bindings for each site to include bindings for the respective IP's

[image]

You'd set your IP address for the IP of the respective domain name and then select that domain's certificate in the drop-down.  Then you want to make sure that no other sites have bindings for those domain names or IP's.

That should do it for you.

Comment: That's what i did... however when i put in the IP address, I can no longer reach the site.  Any ideas?

Comment: What are the error(s) you get?

Comment: Not a lot.  Just a 404 page not found when i change the IP address from * to the specific one.  Tried with host headers and appCmd, still no joy.  Can only seem to get it working with *, which doesnt' allow me distinguish between the sites.

Comment: Do you have a wildcard binding on any other sites?

Comment: Only on a custom port (6326)... just stopped this website and still no joy however

Comment: That is how it's supposed to work - definitely. The IP Addresses are valid on the server, aren't they? Or do you "just" NAT?

Comment: What you did should basically work but do require that everything be valid on the server. This includes certificates being installed to the machine account, IPs be set up properly on server NICs, and DNS be set up to point to the correct IPs. Having done this, all specific bindings should just work. Just make sure you removed all wildcards.